# Tensorflow tile throws TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

Was trying out this code to generate a expanded array with a range of numbers, but this is throwing a error in line `d = tf.tile(k, [m])`

```
import tensorflow as tf

min_rating = tf.constant(0, tf.int64)
max_rating = tf.constant(12, tf.int64)
m = max_rating - min_rating + 1
k = tf.range(m, dtype=tf.int64)
d = tf.tile(k, [m])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = sess.run([d])
    print a
```

Here is the error log:

```
    d = tf.tile(k, [m])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3740, in tile
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 493, in apply_op
    raise err
TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

I couldn't find any reference. Is `tf.range` returning a sequence of tensor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[m]` in line `d = tf.tile(k, [m])` is the "List of Tensors" the error refers to. I guess you parenthesized `m` for making the `multiples` argument of `tf.tile` a 1-D Tensor. It only turned out that `[m]` is just a list of Tensors. You might want to use `tf.reshape` to make a 1-D Tensor, i.e. change the error line to:

```
d = tf.tile(k, tf.reshape(m, [1]))
```

Comment: Thanks that worked ! Tensorflow errors can be unintuitive sometimes. However I had to cast `M` to `int32`. I've detailed the issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18749)